# How do I take a sceenshot in unity8 (mir desktop)?

Tags: screenshot, mir, unity8

I'm trying unity8 (mir desktop) and I don't know how to take a screenshot.

Comment: what does the printscreen button do?

Comment: Nothing seems to happen with the print button, I don't know if it does anything without showing it to me. I checked under Pictures and there's no screenshot there.

Comment: does `gnome-screenshot -w` in terminal do anything?

Comment: sorry, gnome-screenshot cannot open an X display server session under mir

Answer (score 0):

Launch GIMP and go to “File”->”Create”->”Screenshot”

Comment: I don't have gimp, but I'm quite sure that an X app under the mir display server can see only its portion of the screen

Comment: I was looking at bug reports made in 2015 and it appears you haven't been the only person to experience this problem. Have you made sure and update to the latest version? They say it has been fixed in the latest update.

Answer (score -1):

Press the Print key (the screen should flash once). You can find the screenshot under

```
/home/$user/Pictures/Screenshots
```